# MapBox Hide Layer Button Text Change

Tags: mapbox

Sorry of this is a simple question but I have a Mapbox map with 2 layers running on my website. Each layer can be toggled on or off using the example code on the MapBox support site.

However it uses the name of the layers directly for the text of the menu buttons. Is there a way to change this to a more aesthetically pleasing title?

Many thanks

Col

Code added below :

```
map.on('load', function() {
    // add source and layer for 2020 Tour
    map.addSource('pjuk-2020-tour', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://styles/silentwitness/cka13nxh44g1v1iqd7xxr1nys'
    });

map.addLayer({
    'id': 'pjuk-2020-tour',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'pjuk-2020-tour',
    'layout': {
        // make layer visible by default
        'visibility': 'visible'
    },
    'source-layer': 'pjuk-2020-tour'
});



    map.addSource('pjuk-previous-tours', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://styles/silentwitness/cka13nxh44g1v1iqd7xxr1nys'
    });

map.addLayer({
    'id': 'pjuk-previous-tours',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'pjuk-previous-tours',
    'layout': {
        // make layer visible by default
        'visibility': 'visible'
    },
    'source-layer': 'pjuk-previous-tours'
});


});



// enumerate ids of the layers
var toggleableLayerIds = ['pjuk-2020-tour', 'pjuk-previous-tours'];


// set up the corresponding toggle button for each layer
for (var i = 0; i < toggleableLayerIds.length; i++) {
var id = toggleableLayerIds[i];

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = '#';
link.className = 'active';
link.textContent = id;
```

Comment: Would you be able to clarify what you mean by "a more aesthetically pleasing title"? I am assuming you are referring to this example: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/. Can you confirm if this is the example you are referring to? If so, it would be helpful if you could provide an example of what you'd want the menu to look like.

Comment: Please provide an example.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. Yes, apologies for not linking the example. That is the code I am using - in this instance the menu titles of museums and contours are taken directly from the layer titles brought in from MapBox. In my case the layer titles are 'pjuk_previous_tours' and 'pjuk_2020_tour'. I would like to change the menu titles that are created to show 'PJUK Previous Tours' and 'PJUK 2020 Tour'.

I have tried to find this for some time on the internet but I've been unsuccessful in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/) as a model, there are many ways which you could go about doing this. One is to create a variable storing a mapping from the desired title to the name of the layer, so that clicking on the relevant button will use the `textContent` as a key in this mapping to retrieve a value representing the name of the layer. For example:

```
var titleToLayerName = {
  'PJUK Previous Tours': 'pjuk_previous_tours',
  'PJUK 2020 Tour': 'pjuk_2020_tour'
}

...

link.onclick = function(e) {
  var clickedLayer = titleToLayerName[this.textContent];
  ... 
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Works perfectly.